# Programmatically Set APN Settings wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i started to devellop application to get setting system parameters of device automatically with windows phone 7

my problem is how can setting APN and proxy of the device programmatically( windows API or program c#) in windows phone 7 or windows phone 8

please if an expert in windows phone have an idea help me .

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge there's no way to access such settings in WP7 but there's a hop in WP8

Check this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: There is nothing in WP8 that allows this.